# Rails helper to find the current path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, helper

I am trying to make a helper that adds Bootstrap "active" class to nav tabs on current page in browser. Problem is that I have categories and their subcategories, so I want categories tab to be active also when current page is a subcategory of that category.

This works:

```
  def active?(category)
    "active" if current_page?(category_path(category) || category_subcategory_path(category, 1))
  end
```

But as you see I hardcoded the subcategory id - 1 (just to test it works). I thought I could just pass `category.subcategory` instead of 1, but then I get  **undefined subcategory for category with id 1** because my categories table dont have any reference to subcategories (only subcategories table has a *category_id* row), so I guess I should define subcategory somehow in Categories controller, but how?

Also thought to grab the last segment of URI (http://localhost:3000/categories/2/subcategories/5), but it doesn't look as a convenient way for this.

```
   <% @categories.each do |cat| %>
     <li class="<%= active?(cat) %>">
       <%= link_to cat.name.titleize, category_path(cat) %></td>
     </li>
   <% end %>
   <% @category.subcategories.each do |subcategory| %>
     <li>
       <%= link_to subcategory.name.titleize, category_subcategory_path(@category, subcategory) %></td>
     </li>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: Why doesn't grabbing the subcategoryid from the url look convenient?

Comment: @Iceman - because I expect more from Rails :) There is a connection between categories and subcategories, so should be a way to establish it here also, I think. Also because later I will remove category and subcategory id from the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it with:

```
  def active?(category)
    "active" if
      current_page?(category_path(category)) || 
      current_page?(category_subcategory_path(controller: 'subcategories', action: 'show', category_id: category))
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following method to your `Category` model:

```
def has_child?(subcat)
  subcategories.include?(subcat) # probably better to match against ids
end
```

this method will return `true` if a specific category record has the passed-in `subcategory`.

inside your `SubcategoriesHelper` add the following method:

```
def category_class(cat, subcat)
  cat.has_child?(subcat) ? 'active' : '' 
end
```

this will return `"active"` if `has_child?` is true

Now you can use this `category_class` helper method inside the `subcategories#show` view when iterating through `Category` records:

```
...
<% @categories.each do |cat| %>
  <li class="<%= category_class(cat, @subcategory) %>">
    <%= cat.title %>
  </li>
<% end %>
...
```

Comment: `category.subcategories` I tried, for sure - no errors but not working as well.. My association  is simple - has_many and belongs_to

Comment: yep, but for ex. `category.subcategories.first` works the same as `"active" if current_page?(category_subcategory_path(category, 1))` - I mean works fine with that particular subcategory